# I get "ALERT Error in Content Enumeration." whener I try to save in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

Whenever I try to save whether it is with my phone, autosave or sleeping in a bed it always says:

> ALERT Error in Content Enumeration.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

[Rockstar have stated](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203709166-Progress-not-saving-on-xbox-one) that you should contact support if this error occurs:

> Please [create a ticket](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/requests/new) and we will troubleshoot through all these issues with you. We apologize for an inconveniences you have witnessed.

Comment: What if that OP has a Xbox One and no PS 3?(as he stated)

Comment: Oh i dint see the tag..... i made an edit

Answer (score 0):

From the [same article](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203709166-Progress-not-saving-on-xbox-one) link posted by Rishit Bansal:

> My problem was fixed when I changed my power settings on my xbox one, to energy savings. Which turns off the console and the power supply completely. White light is stand by mode, orange light is completely off.
>
> Here is a link to the video on Youtube that helped me out. For me, I have an Xbox One.
>
> Hope this helps. As for PS4 goes, I don't have an answer.

In other words, try cutting power to your Xbox or PS3 completely. Shut it down so it goes into 'standby' mode, and turn it off at the wall. Wait 30 seconds, and turn it back on.